Is there a way to limit what columns are used in the selectors search without opening the selector?
I'm trying to get the InventoryID selector on the Sales Order screen to only search on the InventoryCD and not the Description as well.
I have tried to use the Customisations Project to add the InventoryID to the Quick Filters and Disabling the Filter By All Fields

As well as removing all Columns from the selector Except of the InventoryID
But it will still search on both the ID/CD and Description


